# How to Include JS File To Component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have many components and i want to include js files each. I have to use 3rd party js files and this js files are specific for any component. I mean that these js files are not global, they are component specific. So, i want to include a js file to component.

How to i include js files to components ?

### index.html ( main html in project )

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <base href="/">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body class="fixed-navbar">
  <div class="site">

    <app-root></app-root>

  </div>

  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script></script>


  <!-- Component Specific JS Files Have To Come Here -->
  <!-- Component Specific JS Files Have To Come Here -->
  <!-- Component Specific JS Files Have To Come Here -->
  <!-- Component Specific JS Files Have To Come Here -->
  <!-- Component Specific JS Files Have To Come Here -->


</body>

</html>
```

---

### post.component.html ( component html )

```
<p> Post 1</p>
<p> Post 2 </p>
<p> Post Bla bla bla </p>



<!-- This scripts is only for this component -->
<!-- This js section has to go to specific place in index.html where i type -->

<script src="/assets/plugins/parallax/parallax.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('.easypiechart').easyPieChart();
  });
</script>

<!-- Angular doesn't include these scripts to page -->
```

---

### user.component.html ( component html )

```
<p> User 1 </p>
<p> User2 </p>
<p> User Bla bla bla </p>



<!-- This scripts is only for this component -->
<!-- This js section has to go to specific place in index.html where i type -->

<script src="/assets/plugins/anotherjs/anotherjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/chart2/jquery.chart2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular doesn't include these scripts to page -->
```

---

**I can't add js files by using "`<script>`" tag in *.component.html**

**Angular doesnt agree that usage.**

Comment: You are using Angular. You shouldn't be injecting JS files. Look for the NPM package. If it's not there, most likely it's an old library what you are trying to use.

Comment: This is how angular works i think. I'm new at this. Getting understand. Thank you so much. When i need a third party js plugin, i have to download its npm package, everytime, right ? Thanks, @Patricio Vargas

Comment: correct. everytime you need a third party library look for the npm package.

Answer (score 3):

In case, if anyone is still struggling in 2022, and he/she wants to add JS file in any one component. This is how I did:

**In component.ts file:**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";//Change to your js file
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    node.async = true;
    node.charset = 'utf-8';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
 }
```

Comment: The path to the script can be for example `node.src = "assets/somescript.js";` if you have the script in assets folder.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add external files in the template.

You can add them in the `index.html` or inside `scripts` in the `angular-cli.json`

Ideally you should not include the entire script if possible and use node modules and `import` them as necessary in the corresponding component `ts`

Answer (score 1):

Including jQuery in your Angular components leads to misery but if you really are determined to go down that path you do it in your TypeScipt file of your component, not in the template.

First you need to install jQuery to your app.

```
npm install jquery --save
```

In your angular-cli.json add:

```
],
"scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"],
```

Now in you app.component.ts, you will need to import jQuery:

```
import * as $ from "jquery"
```

Now you can write your jQuery after on init

```
ngOnInit() {
  $...add your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `addScript()` method and use it in `ngOnInit()`. If you need it in any other components, you can create a `ScriptService` and use it in components.

```
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-x',
    templateUrl: './app-x.component.html'
})
export class AppX implements OnInit {
    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: Document) {
    }

    private addScript(scriptSrc: string) {
        const script = this.document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = scriptSrc;
        script.async = true;
        this.document.head.appendChild(script);
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.addScript('assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js');
        this.addScript('assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js');
    }
}
```